# how can i embed javascript developed by Create React App

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox, gis

I want to use javascript library on github in my project but I don't know how to do it.

the scripts are "https://github.com/ReyhaneMasumi/mapbox-gl-draw-scale-rotate-mode"

Is there any way to use this library on plain web app project?

Comment: Its usage and installation are already mentioned in the Readme file https://github.com/ReyhaneMasumi/mapbox-gl-draw-scale-rotate-mode. You can do `npm install` or add the script in the HTML file and use it as mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You just should check installation and usage guide in **README.md**:
https://github.com/ReyhaneMasumi/mapbox-gl-draw-scale-rotate-mode#readme
[image]